# react-google-maps KMlLayer 2d, 3d kmz file or kml file highlighted layer not showing

Tags: react-google-maps

-- KMlLayer 2d, 3d kmz file or kml file highlighted layer not showing .
-- After render kmlfile Measurement or lables of kml line not showing
I am trying to  display kml file on react google map Highlighting image not showing